# I wrote a program to replace all characters in the inputted string with the alphabet in order, but I dont get why it isn't working as intended

Tags: python, string, replace

This may seem like a beginner question, but I'm new to python and don't know much.

So this program is supposed to take the inputted string and replace all the characters in it with the alphabet in order, for eg. inputting `"python"` should output `"abcdef"` and inputting `"program"` should output `"abcdefg"` etc.

```
import string
char = input()
new_char = "-"
for i, let in enumerate(char):
  new_char = char.replace(let, string.ascii_letters[i])
  char = new_char
print(new_char)
```

For some reason, it only replaces some of the characters with random letters and not in order. But when I replace the `i` in `string.ascii_letters[i]` with any index from 0 - 51, then the program works as intended. Could someone explain to me why this program is not working as intended?

Comment: `.replace` replaces all occurrences of the given letter (`let`). So for example in "program", you've replaced first "p" with "a", but when you get to the second-to-last "a" in the word, you replace all the "a"s (including the one that at the start of `char` now) with the "f". If what you've explained is all you need, you can just do `char = string.ascii_letters[:len(char)]`.

Comment: I put the third arguement `1`, `.replace(old, new, 1)`, which will only replace the first occurence of the letter, but the program still doesn't seem to work properly. Im guessing the problem is that `.replace` replaces the initial occurences of the given string, `n` times, where n is the third arguement. So if the replace encounters a duplicate letter for example g, it will replace the first occurence of g in the string instead of the one it is supposed to. Is there some sort of fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to complicate it. `ascii_lowercase` prints all the lower case letters. It returns a string. So taking advantage of slicing, you can do string slicing

```
import string
char = input()
new_char = string.ascii_lowercase[:len(char)]
print(new_char)
```

`.replace` replaces all the occurrences of a particular substring. So, if you do `program` and you replace it, it becomes `arogram`. Notice that you assign that to `new_char`. With next iteration, it will become `abogbam`

Comment: I like this way better than mine. ;) More pythonic for sure.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `chr()` to convert from int to characters (don't forget that the input is ASCII char codes)
- If you don't care about the value in the input string, just iterate over `for i in range(len(input_string)):`
- `char.replace(old_chr, new_chr)` will replace *all instances* of `old_chr` throughout the whole string (what if your input is `hello`?)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
import string
char = input()
new_char = ''
for x in range(len(char)):
    new_char += string.ascii_letters[x]
print(new_char)
```